# Simple navigation forced close on emulator

Tags: android, debugging

I am new to Android development.
Been recently tried to have my own Facebook like sliding out menu , but can't get it work , **its doesn't contain any error in eclipse checking and build up , but when i run it on emulator , the emulator gave me a force close error just no reason**.Have done a lot of 
this is the tutorial i follow [Johnkil Sidenavigation](https://github.com/johnkil/SideNavigation)

have done some reseach on debugging technique but don't know where should i start ,
**But i think it is just my layout problem , What am i missing?**
Here is part of my code , please let me know how kind of information i need to provide

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.nazartt.johntest;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {
    SideNavigationView sideNavigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SideNavigationView sideNavigationView = (SideNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.side_navigation_view);
        sideNavigationView.setMenuItems(R.menu.side_navigation_menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                sideNavigationView.toggleMenu();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    } 


}
```

here is part my related xml code

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    <com.devspark.sidenavigation.SideNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/side_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is insert menu folder...
side_navigation_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</menu>
```

here is the logcat,

```
    12-28 05:29:33.643: E/Trace(11550): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-28 05:29:33.656: E/AndroidRuntime(11550): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-28 05:29:33.656: E/AndroidRuntime(11550): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.nazartt.johntest/com.nazartt.johntest.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nazartt.johntest.MainActivity
12-28 05:29:33.656: E/AndroidRuntime(11550):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
12-28 05:29:33.656: E/AndroidRuntime(11550):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-28 05:29:33.656: E/AndroidRuntime(11550):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-28 05:29:33.656: E/AndroidRuntime(11550):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-28 05:29:33.656: E/AndroidRuntime(11550):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-28 05:29:33.656: E/AndroidRuntime(11550):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-28 05:29:33.656: E/AndroidRuntime(11550):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-28 05:29:33.656: E/AndroidRuntime(11550):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-28 05:29:33.656: E/AndroidRuntime(11550):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-28 05:29:33.656: E/AndroidRuntime(11550):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-28 05:29:33.656: E/AndroidRuntime(11550):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-28 05:29:33.656: E/AndroidRuntime(11550):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-28 05:29:33.656: E/AndroidRuntime(11550): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nazartt.johntest.MainActivity
12-28 05:29:33.656: E/AndroidRuntime(11550):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
12-28 05:29:33.656: E/AndroidRuntime(11550):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-28 05:29:33.656: E/AndroidRuntime(11550):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-28 05:29:33.656: E/AndroidRuntime(11550):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
12-28 05:29:33.656: E/AndroidRuntime(11550):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
12-28 05:29:33.656: E/AndroidRuntime(11550):    ... 11 more
```

here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nazartt.johntest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.nazartt.johntest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.nazartt.johntest.ISideNavigationCallback"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.nazartt.johntest.SideNavigationItem"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.nazartt.johntest.SideNavigationView"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the logcat stack trace please

Comment: @Simon Thanks for the reply , which part of logcat i should provide ? should i filter with the error only?

Comment: Yes, just the error please.

Comment: @Simon Updated part of my code and logcat . Meanwhile I had moved the tutorial library into my own project because the tutorial library only contain few classes and picture , but i still can't get it work

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nazartt.johntest.MainActivity`  Looks like something wrong in your manifest.  Please post it.

Comment: Alright got some idea on reading the error thanks , i updated with manifest

Comment: What API version are you using?  Try changing this `android:name="com.nazartt.johntest.MainActivity"` to this `android:name=".MainActivity"`

Comment: I'm not sure Which Api you asked , but target min-api from 8 to the latest 17 , the emulator using api level 16 with the atom processor format

Comment: Yes but the problem still persist , end up i gave up on tutorial , i think i need more dig into android project setup , the buggy environment really did confuse me a lot , anyway thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up restudy about android project setup and download some android example from github and learn how they setup and import library. To newbies who might encounter the same problem , make sure you understand how an android application build , especially when you importing other library into your project.
Important path to look at when you want to import a library

```
Project->properties->android
Project->properties->java build path
```